# Press and hold a key using pynput

Tags: python, pynput

Is there any way to have pynput hold down on a key instead of just pressing it once? I have checked other posts on this website and none of them really help. `keyboard.press` only presses a key once, and doesn't hold it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library called pyAutoGui. It has the functions that you are looking for. Not sure how to do it within pynput